# Cannot convert value of type 'Astronaut.Type' to expected argument type 'Astronaut'

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui

What's happening here, I'm trying to make toggle between ListLayout and GridLayout, but when I make separete GridLayout I always get this error in preview part of code, here is code for GridLayout:

```
import SwiftUI

struct GridLayout: View {
    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150))
    ]

let astronauts: [String: Astronaut] = Bundle.main.decode("astronauts.json")
let missions: [Mission] = Bundle.main.decode("missions.json")

let mission: Mission
let astronaut: Astronaut

var body: some View {
    ScrollView{
    LazyVGrid(columns:columns){
        ForEach(missions) { mission in
            NavigationLink{
                MissionView(mission: mission, astronauts: astronauts)
            } label: {
                VStack{
                    Image(mission.image)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .padding()
                    
                    VStack {
                        Text(mission.displayName)
                             .font(.headline)
                             .foregroundColor(.white)
                         Text(mission.formattedLaunchDate)
                             .font(.caption)
                             .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.5))
                                                
                                        }
                    .padding(.vertical)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(.lightBackground)
                }
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke(.lightBackground)
                )
            }
    }
      
}.padding([.horizontal, .bottom])
}
}
}

struct GridLayout_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        GridLayout(mission: Mission, astronaut: Astronaut)
    }
}
```

And here is code for ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingGrid = true

    let astronauts: [String: Astronaut] = Bundle.main.decode("astronauts.json")
    let missions: [Mission] = Bundle.main.decode("missions.json")

    let columns = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 150))
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if showingGrid {
                    GridLayout
                } else {
                    ListLayout
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Moonshot")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Toggle") {
                    showingGrid.toggle()
                }
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
            }
            .background(.darkBackground)
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Error is in GridLayout:
Cannot convert value of type 'Astronaut.Type' to expected argument type 'Astronaut'
Cannot convert value of type 'Mission.Type' to expected argument type 'Mission'

Comment: `GridLayout(mission: Mission, astronaut: Astronaut)`, you are using the class name, not the value. I guess you meant using `let mission: Mission; let astronaut: Astronaut`, so it should be instances: `GridLayout(mission: mission, astronaut: astronaut)`

Comment: `Instance member 'astronaut' cannot be used on type 'GridLayout_Previews'`

it show this error then

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to proved enough code so we can run it ourselves. @Larme comment is correct, but you obviously have some other error in code that you are not showing.